# Set Oozie coordinator start date to beginning of current quater

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to run an oozie job for daterange as quater to date. How do I set it up to get the start-instance to have beginning of quarter date

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest way would be to start at the beginning of a quarter and set the frequency to every three months:

```
<coordinator-app name="coord"
                 frequency="${coord:months(3)}"
                 start="2015-01-01T00:00Z"
                 end=  "2115-01-01T00:00Z"
                 timezone="UTC"
                 xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.1">
```